# How do I call onCreateMenuOptions just once when the fragment is being created

Tags: android, kotlin, oncreateoptionsmenu

My activity contains many fragments and it has been found that every time a bottom sheet fragment opens up in the activity, the onCreateOptionsMenu function gets called again. How do I ensure that the function gets called only during the start of the Activity

I tried using add menu provider, setHasMenuOptions and invalidate function.

Comment: In the end this expected behavior. Can we know why you would like to avoid multiple calls to onCreateOptionsMenu?

Comment: So the thing is onCreateOptionsMenu inflates the menu which contains bookmark and tracking bell as menu items. Every time a call happens to onCreateOptionsMenu the menu gets inflated as a result of which the state of the menu item is not saved ( We have to handle this separately which we wish to avoid )